# Form submits on wrong button click in React

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

Strange, my entire component keeps submitting by clicking the incorrect button.

The layout:

`B Component` is inside `Component A`. `A Component` has the form. `B Component` triggers the form submit and I dont know why.

**In the return function of A Component:**

```
<form action... method...>
  <BComponent />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**B Component:**

```
...

_removeFile: function(num){
  // issue if function is empty
},

_fileRender: function(){
  var files = this.state.fileDetails.map( function(f, x) {
    return(
      <div key={x}>
        <div className="">
          <button onClick={this._removeFile.bind(this, x)}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }.bind(this));
  return(<div>{files}</div>)
},

render: function(){
  return(<div>{this._fileRender()}</div>)
}

...
```

So when I click the remove button, the form submits. Why? That button passes data to `_removeFile()`. Regardless if that function's empty or not, it still submits. `e.preventDefault()` does nothing. My knowledge at this stage is limited so excuse the silly mistake, if any.

Worst case is to put `Component A`'s submit button into an `onClick()`.

Comment: can you provide component's code

Comment: It's a lot. I'll see if I can slim it down to get the same error. I'll reply in a bit. Thanks

Comment: i'm testing your code right now.  I'll reply in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any button will submit its parent form. This is what buttons do :)

If you need a button but want to prevent the default action you need to use `event.preventDefault()`.

Since you prepopulate an argument to the function using `.bind`, the `event` object will be passed as the second argument:

```
 _removeFile: function(num, e){
     // do stuff with num
     e.preventDefault();
  },
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47187/

Comment: I remembered placing the "e" before the "num". Hah! Maybe that's why i never got it work in the first place. I'll try this later. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**1**.**you may use**  `<input type="button"/>`, **without  event.preventDefault()**

***[your updated code > JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dilajepede/1/edit?js,console,output)***

```
<input type="button" value="remove" onClick={this._removeFile.bind(this, x)}/>
```

in React documentation's [examples](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#submitting-the-form) you may notice that they prefer to use `<input type="submit"/> and <input type="button"/>`

---

**2**.**in your map's callback you may use arrow func, in order to not bind**

```
 var files = this.state.fileDetails.map((f, x)=> 
      <div key={x}>
        <div className="">
          <button onClick={this._removeFile.bind(this, x)}>Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes. Button.